# Where can I find a Pathfinder charsheet PSD?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, character-sheets

I am looking to customize my pathfinder sheet to remove things I don't use and add some houserules elements of my DM. All of us in the party can use these things.

I have searched for a charsheet for Pathfinder in Photoshop PSD format but I have found none :| Does anyone have access to such a resource?

I would be happy with a 3.5 version at the very least.

Comment: I won´t post it as an awnser since it doesn´t really gives you a link for the sheet. I would suggest you to create your onw character sheet on Microsoft Word. It was surprisingly easy - I took around a hour to create from scratch a character sheet for my game (with campaing logo and everything else, plus all house-rules.) It was a 3.5/PF style sheet, so your problem is basically the same.

Comment: More interested in the graphics associated with it. Easy to make some text fields and whatnot. It is for our gameplay, I am not looking to make money off it.

Comment: Well, that was just my point. I created everything in Word, even the graphics. When I get home I will post my sheet, so you can see for yourself how it goes. It´s portuguese, tho.

Comment: Not the official sheets but this: http://charactersheets.minotaur.cc/ contains some really great sheets that you can mix and match. The whole thing is open source, but they're all Illustrator files, iirc.

Comment: @Cthos put this in an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the official character sheets, but [charactersheets.minotaur.cc](http://charactersheets.minotaur.cc) is a very nice character sheet set, complete with a site to customize which sheets you're downloading.

Even, better, all of the sheets are released as open source, which means you can modify them to your heart's content. The github repository for the files is at https://github.com/marcusatbang/charactersheets. It looks like all of the files are Adobe Illustrator files, which can be made into PSDs from Illustrator.

Comment: Nice find! Who needs the *official* sheets when such a nice alternative is available?

Answer (score 1):

You won't find such a thing online, not legally. The official Pathfinder character sheets *are* still copyrighted material, even if they give them away free of charge. Nobody (except Paizo) can legally post a PSD version of the sheets online.

Consequently, there's no shortcut available if you want to make your own private custom sheet directly based on Paizo's. You'll have to import the PDF (or a rasterised version of its pages) into Photoshop and trace it yourself to re-create it in PSD format, and make the customisations you like in the meantime.

Comment: No mention of unofficial, or fan-based versions?

Comment: @YogoZuno I read it as wanting to customise the sheet they were already using, and I assumed the official sheet therefore. Cthos has ably come along after and provided an answer from the "unofficial is OK" assumption, and I'm OK with that. :)